# React: Convert a component into a HTML & CSS String

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been working on a Card UI generator in React and once the user is finished with customising it using the UI I want to be able to convert the card (that's a React Component) and export the HTML and CSS behind it. Is there a way to turn a component into HTML String?

Comment: Copy it from your browser?

Comment: I want the user to hit a button that will take the component they've edited in browser and then get all the HTML & CSS for it

Comment: What kind of edit will a user make?

Comment: Is it important that it's css? it would be easier to use inline styles then it would be a case of element.outerHTML

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ReactDOMServer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html):

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the testing tool it is possible to render a component into a string. Maybe that fits your use-case?
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `create-react-app`, you can create the production-ready build by using [npm run build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build). That will create the HTML and CSS for you.

If you're looking to render particular components, you might look into [server-side rendering](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e).

Comment: I might have worded the question wrong, what I meant is that I only want it to export a single component as HTML and CSS so people can copy paste the code into their projects. Think of a CSS button generator but for cards :)

Comment: Ah, I see, well, maybe server-side rendering could help you out. Updated my answer. You could render them on the server, in an iframe, for example, and then grab the source.